# Get specific row from array where column is set to a given value

Tags: php, mysql

My objective is to create a multi-language web site.
At first, I plan to have only 3 languages (French, German, and English).

The welcome page will be displayed in English and then next pages will be localized thanks to a variable carried through a php session.

I created a table page2 with the following columns:

```
Field_name | English | German | French
```

Table contains:

```
Name | "Your name" | "Ihre Name" | "Votre nom"

Street | "Streetname" | "Ihre Strasse" | "Votre rue"

...
```

php code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM page2;";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

I want to display the table contents (in several parts of the page) in the appropriate language.

If in English:
Your name: Smith (value retrieved from another table - not the question here!)

If in German:
Ihre Name: Smith (value retrieved from another table - not the question here!)

My question is how to have "Your name" or "Ihre Name" or "Votre nom" such as:

```
echo $result['Name'][column=$lang];
```

Display "English" column value of row "Name" if English is set in $lang

Display "German" column value of row "Name" if German is set in $lang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this:

```
    $arrResult = array();
    $sql    = "SELECT * FROM page2";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while($row    = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
    $arrResult[$row['field_name']] =  $row;
    }

    echo $arrResult['Name']['English'];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
$query = "SELECT `$language` FROM `page2` WHERE `Field_name` = 'Street'";
echo $result[$language];
```

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much have it already:

```
$lang="German";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM page2 where field_name='Name'";
// etc...
echo $result[$lang];
```

Just enter the `field_name` as you need and either access the result of the array "English", "German" or "French".

Answer (score 0):

I dont fully understand the way you are describing your tables, but this should give you a general idea of one way to do it. We add all the results to a array named $names. Then for every row we add a key with the language, and under there we add the name of the person in that language.

```
$names = array();
for( $i=0; $r=mysql_fetch_assoc( $sql ); $i++ ){
    $names[$i][$r['language']] = $r['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to deviate from the pattern of other answers here and suggest that your data model is incorrect and should be changed.

Having a column for each language requires you to modify the *structure of your table* when you want to add more languages.  I believe it would make much more sense to modify the *data in your table* to achieve this:

```
field_name | lang | value
-----------+------+-------------
name       | EN   | Your name
name       | DE   | Ihre Name
name       | FR   | Votre nom
street     | EN   | Streetname
street     | DE   | Ihre Strasse
...
```

This way you can use a query like so:

```
select * from page2 where lang = ?
```

<strike>and then simply use `$result['name']` and `$result['street']` in your code.</strike>  See edit 2, below.

Adding a new language is as simple as executing an `insert` statement.

---

***Edit***

I strongly recommend you read '[Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)'

---

***Edit 2***

As noted by ChristopheL, the following method is needed to retrieve the values:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $arrResult[$row['field_name']] = $row;
}
echo $arrResult['name']['value'];
echo $arrResult['street']['value'];
```

Comment: Hello Tim, I tried to implement my datamodel as you suggested. However, I do not manage to display the results. $sql = "SELECT field_name, value FROM page2"; $results = mysql_query ($sql); echo $results['name']; It does not display anything. Any idea? ChristopheL

Comment: Hello @ChristopheL. I must have been having a bad day when I wrote this, as it won't work! I'll revise my answer when I get a moment.

Comment: Hello Tim, I made it work with:
$sql = "SELECT field_name, value FROM page2";
$results = mysql_query ($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $arrResult[$row['field_name']] =  $row;
}
echo $arrResult['name']['value'];
echo $arrResult['street']['value'];
Cheers, ChristopheL.